# Remove method to remove specific object from ArrayList not working

Tags: java

So I have a Java files named `ConeList` and `ConeListMenuApp`. In `ConeListMenuApp` I have a switch method that allows the user to read in a file that populates an `ArrayList` with `Cone` objects. One of the other options is to delete a cone. The user is prompted to enter a label (name of the cone) and then the `deleteCone` method from my `ConeList` is called. For some reason, I keep getting an issue where that cone is not being found in the `ArrayList`. It returns ""Label Entered" not found." Which would make sense except its there as my methods for printing and finding it both show it. Here is my code for the `deleteCone` method.

```
   public Cone deleteCone(String labelIn) {

  int index = -1;
  Cone c = null;
  for (Cone d : conesList) {
     if (d.getLabel() == labelIn)  {
        index = conesList.indexOf(d);
        break;
     }
  }
  
  
  if (index >= 0) {
    
     c = conesList.remove(index);
  }
  return c;
```

If anyone could help me out with understanding where my issue may lie I would greatly appreciate it. I am fairly new to java and sort of stuck trying to figure out why I'm not able to remove the object.

Comment: `d.getLabel() == labelIn` - should this not be `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()`

Comment: If you had stepped through your remove method in the debugger you would have quickly seen what was wrong.